# Merging two lists of dictionaries with shared keys throughout the dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries:

```
# shop_qs
[{'month': 'Jul', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('180')}, {'month': 'Aug', 'sales': 2, 'revenue': Decimal('525')}]
# com_qs
[{'month': 'Jun', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('200')}, {'month': 'Aug', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('450')}]
```

I am attempting to merge the dictionaries in the two lists by month and then add the values in the sales fields and the values in the revenue fields together, for that month.

This is what I have attempted to far but, as you can see, yields a result no where near what is desired.

```
total_chained_ls = list(chain(shop_qs, com_qs))
total_ls = defaultdict(int)
for d in total_chained_ls:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, decimal.Decimal):
            total_ls[k] = total_ls[k] + v
        else:
            total_ls[k] = v

# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'month': 'Aug', 'sales': 5, 'revenue': Decimal('1355')})
```

This is the desired output:

```
[{'month': 'Jun', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('200')}, {'month': 'Jul', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('180')}, {'month': 'Aug', 'sales': 3, 'revenue': Decimal('975')}]
```

How would you go about doing this in Python?

*Note: the `Decimal` values in the fields acts like a normal int.*

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please post the code you've tried with an explanation of how its output differs from the desired output.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Well that's the issue and the reason for asking. I have tried multiple ways but have not succeeded even close to what I have wanted. Posting the code I have tried will yield no benefit.

Comment: @TerminalFlow, it will show your efforts and let others correct you and point you to mistakes you've made which considered to be better for educational purposes than just provide a solution.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I have updated the question. Any advice?

Comment: @TerminalFlow, there are couple of ways. You can declare `total_ls` as simple `dict` and use values of `'month'` as keys of `total_ls` and sum values of `'sales'` and `'revenue'` keys. After this you can generate output in desire format. Another option is to use `groupby()` on sorted chain of `shop_qs` and `com_qs`, like this: `[{'month': m, 'sales': sum(map(itemgetter('sales'), g)), 'revenue': sum(map(itemgetter('revenue'), g))} for m, [*g] in groupby(sorted(chain(shop_qs, com_qs), key=itemgetter('month')), itemgetter('month'))]`. Of course, you shouldn't keep a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

See if this could help you:

```py
from decimal import *
# shop_qs
lst_1 = [{'month': 'Jul', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('180')}, {'month': 'Aug', 'sales': 2, 'revenue': Decimal('525')}]
# com_qs
lst_2 = [{'month': 'Jun', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('200')}, {'month': 'Aug', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('450')}]
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   merge list_2 into list_1
for x in lst_2:
    lst_1.append(x)
#   define months of year
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

#   loop months to do the job
lst = []
lst_done = []
for month in months:
    dct = {}
    for d in lst_1:
        # check the month to decide if it should be processed or not
        if d['month'] == month and month not in lst_done: 
            sales = 0
            revenue = 0
            # calculate sums
            if month not in dct.keys():
                sales_list = [ lst_1[j]['sales'] for j in range(len(lst_1)) if lst_1[j]['month'] == month ]
                for x in sales_list:
                    sales += x
                revenue_list = [ lst_1[j]['revenue'] for j in range(len(lst_1)) if lst_1[j]['month'] == month ]
                for x in revenue_list:
                    revenue += x
                # fill in the dictionary for the month and append it to lst     
                dct['month'] = month
                dct['sales'] = sales
                dct['revenue'] = revenue
                lst.append(dct)
            # putting the month into the done list
            lst_done.append(month)
```

```py
'''     R e s u l t i n g   l i s t:   (lst)
[
    {'month': 'Jun', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('200')}, 
    {'month': 'Jul', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('180')}, 
    {'month': 'Aug', 'sales': 3, 'revenue': Decimal('975')}
]
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You correctly applied [`chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to merge lists, but you shouldn't consume returned iterator into a list as it turns whole expression into `shop_qs + com_qs`. As you have static keys where you need to sum values, you don't need to initialize inner loop to iterate over pairs in each dictionary but just make sum manually. With certain edits your code could be turned into this:

```py
from decimal import Decimal
from itertools import chain

shop_qs = [
    {'month': 'Jul', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('180')},
    {'month': 'Aug', 'sales': 2, 'revenue': Decimal('525')}
]
com_qs = [
    {'month': 'Jun', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('200')},
    {'month': 'Aug', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('450')}
]

total_ls = {}
for d in chain(shop_qs, com_qs):
    month = d.pop('month')
    item = total_ls.get(month)
    if item:
        item['sales'] += d['sales']
        item['revenue'] += d['revenue']
    else:
        total_ls[month] = d
```

*Important notice: `dict.pop()` will modify items of both `shop_qs` and `com_qs`.*

After execution your `total_ls` will have data in next format:

```py
{
    'Jul': {
        'sales': 1,
        'revenue': Decimal('180')
    }, 
    'Aug': {
        'sales': 3,
        'revenue': Decimal('975')
    },
    'Jun': {
        'sales': 1,
        'revenue': Decimal('200')
    }
}
```

You can turn it back into list of dictionaries using next list comprehension:

```py
[{'month': k} | v for k, v in total_ls.items()]
# OR (for older python versions)
[{'month': k, **v} for k, v in total_ls.items()]
```

---

Another way to merge items by certain criteria is to use [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) on sorted data.

```py
from decimal import Decimal
from itertools import chain, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

shop_qs = [
    {'month': 'Jul', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('180')},
    {'month': 'Aug', 'sales': 2, 'revenue': Decimal('525')}
]
com_qs = [
    {'month': 'Jun', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('200')},
    {'month': 'Aug', 'sales': 1, 'revenue': Decimal('450')}
]

month_getter = itemgetter('month')
sorted_chained_ls = sorted(chain(shop_qs, com_qs), key=month_getter)
total_ls = []
for _, group in groupby(sorted_chained_ls, month_getter):
    item = next(group)
    total_ls.append(item)
    for i in group:
        item['sales'] += i['sales']
        item['revenue'] += i['revenue']
```